# Creating a Bitmap in c# .net 4 Framework

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am currently working on a small program, that loads an image file into the Console and print it out as an asci image. I am using the ".Net Console application framework 4". My Problem is, that I do not know how to create a Bitmap. After browsing for a while, I found many answers to my question, that suggested the "System.Drawing.Bitmap" class. When I try to refer to this class, visual studio does not even know System.Drawing.Bitmap. I have a class "AsciArt" which should convert the picture in the method ConvertToAsci. Does anybody know what my mistake is?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing.Bitmap;

namespace consoleGrafix

   {


    class AsciArt 
    {
        private string ImgLink;


        public AsciArt(string imageLocation)
        {
            this.ImgLink = imageLocation;
        }


        public void ConvertToAsci(string saveLocation)
        {
            var bm = Bitmap(saveLocation);
        }

}
}
```

Comment: Google "How to add reference to .NET project"

Comment: I know how hat works, Ive done that with directX before..

Comment: the Problem is that System.Drawing does not have a Bitmap class

Comment: maybe this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.0

Comment: "_I know how hat works, Ive done that with directX before.._" I think you misunderstand... Note that your project needs to reference the assembly that provides the type you are after. Which assembly is that? Good that you asked. The documentation linked to in Mario Mitterbauer's comment tells which assembly/assemblies need to be referenced by your project to be able to use System.Drawing.Bitmap...

Comment: Also, `using System.Drawing.Bitmap;` is not going to work, as there is no namespace "System.Drawing.Bitmap" (the semantics of the `using` directive is `using <Namespace>;`). The namespace you want to use is "System.Drawing", that's the namespace of the Bitmap type. Hence, you should do `using System.Drawing;`.

Comment: thank you elgonzo! I had the references correct, though I do not find System.Drawing.Common.dll in vs. I tried to use the bitmap constructor from a wrong direction.

Comment: System.Drawing.Common.dll is an assembly you would use with .NET Core. With .NET Core (and .NET Standard, i guess), assemblies have been somewhat restructured/rearranged in comparison to ye'ole .NET framework. Hence why the documentation lists different assemblies (documentation could be improved in this respect to clearly indicate which assembly names would be valid for which platform/build target...)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set up my class by inheriting from image class. Also, in the ConvertTo Asci method, there was a "new". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.0 . This really helped. Thank you!